# What is better to iterate over an EnumMap in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, enum-map

Suppose I have declared an enum and corresponding emummap as:

```
enum MyEnum {
    CONSTANT1, CONSTANT2, CONSTANT3;
}

EnumMap<MyEnum, String> MyEnumMap = new EnumMap<MyEnum, String>(MyEnum.class);
```

I want to iterate over `MyEnumMap`, for example, just to print each `Entry` one by one.

What is the best approach(fastest) to iterate over keys in the following cases:

1. When it is ensured that each constant in `MyEnum` is a key in `MyEnumMap`
2. When each constant in `MyEnum` may or may not be a key in `MyEnumMap`

I want to choose between foreach loop using `MyEnumMap.keySet()` or `MyEnum.values()`. Any other approach is most welcomed.

Comment: Unless you find that this particular part of your code is a bottleneck in a real life situation, you shouldn't try to optimize it. Use the most readable and clear way.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I agree with you. But I read about this data structure today and want to begin with the simplest but optimised approach to use it. `MyEnumMap.keySet()` or `MyEnum.values()` are both readable but I want to use the better one

Comment: This is called "premature optimization". And it is considered a *bad approach* to programming.

Comment: If you want to print the entries, iterate over the `entrySet` directly.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks for the info. Not offending, but can I know the reason for it as I always try doing the same when learning new functionalities. If I am on the wrong path, please show me the right one.

Comment: @AlexisC. I had used example of printing for questions sake. I may use the keys to search also. Also the value entity will not be a `String` always.

Comment: @Pshemo add your comment as a answer instead. It will help others reading the post.

Comment: "First, make your code -correct- ... and then (and only then) make it fast (and only if profiling warrants it)."  For most use cases, the difference between iterating with `values()` versus iterating with `keySet()` will be immeasurably small.

Comment: Read the [part about when to optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) in Wikipedia's article about optimization. The issue is that if you are giving priority to optimization when you write a program, you'll probably write it less cleanly and it will be more complicated and less easy to write correctly and debug. Therefore, start by making a clean and readable program, and only add optimization at the end if it is needed (a bottleneck is found).

Comment: Your question is kind of strange ... *"When each constant in MyEnum may or may not be a key in MyEnumMap"* When both methods return _different_ results, what is the point in asking about the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at code of `EnumMap#keySet()`

```
381  public Set<K> keySet() {
382      Set<K> ks = keySet;
383      if (ks != null)
384          return ks;
385      else
386          return keySet = new KeySet();
387  }
```

you will notice that it returns `keySet` used internally by `EnumMap` to store keys.

Now each time we call `MyEnum.values()` we are getting different array filled with all enum elements. This means that first empty array is created which later needs to be filled with all enums which requires some iteration.

So in first approach you are skipping iterating over enums already stored by map, while insecond approach we simply creating some temporary array which involves additional iteration over all MyEnum elements.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter. Internally, `EnumMap` is [implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/EnumMap.java) with a pair of arrays of the same length as the number of `enum` entries. One array has `enum` elements, while the second array has objects mapped to them, or `NULL` placeholders. Any iteration over `EnumMap` is therefore equivalent to a `for` loop on an integer index that traverses the entire range of `enum` ordinals, so you should pick the approach that makes your code most readable to you.

Comment: if that is the case, why is it better than a HashMap (as what I read somewhere)? Also if I iterate using `MyEnumMap.keySet()`, I don't get null valued keys for the keys not put explicitly in the map.

Comment: @Mukund It's better than `HashMap` because most `enum`s have a small number of entries. If you make an `enum` with 10,000 entries, and use a map that has ten..fifteen entries, `HashMap` would be faster by an order of magnitude. Note that in my answer I mention `NULL` placeholders. The implementation uses them to skip during the iteration the entries that have not been explicitly set to `null`. See the way the source uses `unmaskNull(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you just want another way of writing the code....
Since keys are always unique

```
for(MyEnum myEnum: MyEnum.values()){
        String value = map.get(myEnum);
         If(value != null){ 
             //use the value here
          }
 }
```

Just another way to write it.

Or you could also try

```
for (Map.Entry<MyEnum, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {       
           System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue()); 
 }
```

Comment: How is this another way? OP is explicitly asking about `MyEnum.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your application logic, but here are some hints:

for 1)

```
 // it is a bit faster to iterate over plain array, than over Set
 // And you can also get here information about entries that are in enum, but not in hashMap, so you can have logic for those cases.
 for (MyEnum e: MyEnum.values()) {
     // you can get here information what is contained and not contained in your map
}
```

for 2) But it is still better to use 1) because you can have there information of enum values not contained in Map.

```
for (MyEnum e: MyEnumMap.keySet()) {
   // you can check here all that is in your map, but you cant tell what is in enum but not in your map
}
```

Comment: can you please justify your answer. And what do you mean by "But it is still better to use 2)"